# How to select with linq to entity Categories and SubCategories?

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq-to-entities

Here is the structure of my Categories table

```
Categories Table
--------------------------------
ID      Name      ParentID

1       NameOne    NULL
2       NameTwo    1
3       NameThree  1
4       NameFour   1
```

Here is my ItemTable that has reference key to category table

```
Items Table
--------------------------------------------
ItemID   CategoryID SubCategoryID      ItemName
1        1          2                  ItemOne
2        1          3                  ItemTwo
```

How can I join it to get unique records like in example below, using LINQ to entity?

The result has to be

```
ItemID               CategoryName   SubCategoryName           ItemName
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
1                    NameOne        NameTwo                   ItemOne
2                    NameOne        NameThree                 ItemTwo
```

Comment: what is unique in the example? `Items`?

Comment: The output should be like you can see in Items the third table from the top

Comment: Is SubCategoryID in your Items table referencing ParentID in the Categories table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you are using entity data model (.edmx file) where you dragged all the necessary tables from the database.

It is hard for me to give you an exact query since I don't know what you have named certain references and models.

Hope this helps you to start:

```
var q = from item in context.Items
        select new {
            ItemID = item.ItemID,
            CategoryName = item.Category.Name,
            SubCategoryName = item.SubCategory.Name,
            ItemName = item.ItemName
        };
```

Please note that "Category" and SubCategory" are references to the entries in Categories table by CategoryId and SubCategoryId in Items table. So replace this to what you have named them in your data model file.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might work depending on how you have your entities defined.

```
var results = Entities.Items.Select( i => new { ItemID = i.ID, CategoryName = i.Category.Name, SubCategoryName = i.SubCategory.Name, ItemName = i.Name } );
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @Mouhannad's assumption:

> I'm assuming you are using entity data model (.edmx file) where you dragged all the necessary tables from the database.

However, if it is not right, then you could try to use join, like this:

```
List<Item> items = someMethodToFillItems();
List<Category> categories = someMethodToFillCategories();

var q = (from item in items join
          cat in categories on cat.Id equals item.CategoryId
          subCat in categories on subCat.ParentId equals cat.Id
    select new {
        ItemID = item.ItemID,
        CategoryName = cat.Name,
        SubCategoryName = subCat.Name,
        ItemName = item.ItemName
    }
);
```